# Common Encryption process for iPhone and Android

Tags: android, encryption

hi guys is there any simple way to encrypt and decrypt the images across platforms like decrypting the image in android encrypted in the iPhone and vise-versa.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1):

You can use **56 bit DES encryption**. It is supported both in iphone and android. You cannot use RSA because image may be larger than 127 byte. Two years before when I was trying with AES 128 bit encryption. I found there was limitation of using AES 128 bit encryption and  put it in market place. So avoid AES also. java supprots AES. Hence nadorid also supports DES

Comment: please google for des encryption and decryption in android as well as in iphone

Answer (score 0):

AES encryption is the best way encrypt a file in android or in IOS.In android I have tried encryption.This link will help you to do in [android](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7297/secure-aes-encryption-and-decryption-in-android) .The below code will help tou to encrypt a byte array with the key in android.

`encryptionKey` will be your password

```
 public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] key, byte[] data) throws Exception

        {

            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(data);
            return encrypted;
        }

        /**
         * DEcrypt byte array with given Key using AES Algorithm
         * Key can be generated using <Code>getKey()</Code>
         * @param key  Key that Is used for decrypting data
         * @param data  Data passed to decrypt
         * @return decrypted data
         * */

        public static byte[] decrypt1(byte[] key, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception
        {

            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
            return decrypted;
        }
        /**
         * get the Key for encryption this can be used for while decrypting and encrypting too.
         * */
        public static byte[] getKey() throws Exception
        {
            byte[] keyStart = EncrypteDecrypte.encryptionKey.getBytes();
            KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            sr.setSeed(keyStart);
            kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
            SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
            byte[] key = skey.getEncoded();

            return key;
        }
```